# Continue after Catch block

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I try to continue the `Try` block after exception.
I mean:

```
Try
    action1()
    action2()
    action3()
    action4()
Catch
    Log()
```

And if found error in `action2` go to Catch, do logging and continue with the `action3`, `action4`;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using array:

```
For Each a As Action In {New Action(AddressOf action1), New Action(AddressOf action2), New Action(AddressOf action3), New Action(AddressOf action4)}
    Try
        a.Invoke()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log(ex)
    End Try
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) as parameter for this method:

```
Public Shared Function TryAction(action As Action) As Boolean
    Dim success As Boolean = True
    Try
        action()
    Catch ex As Exception
        success = False
        Log()
    End Try
    Return success
End Function
```

Now this works:

```
TryAction(AddressOf action1)
TryAction(AddressOf action2)
TryAction(AddressOf action3)
TryAction(AddressOf action4)
```

The classic way using multiple `Try-Catch`:

```
Try
    action1()
Catch
    Log()
End Try
Try
    action2()
Catch
    Log()
End Try
Try
    action3()
Catch
    Log()
End Try
Try
    action4()
Catch
    Log()
End Try
```

Comment: It hwould be good, but sometimes I have to use it with not known elements. I mean in the try I have to use foreach and from the catch I have to go back to thy try block and continue it.

Comment: @Gabor85: you cannot go back from a `catch` into the `try`. What you could do is to repeat the `try` after the `catch`(like a `ReTryTenTimes`-function). You can do that also do with this approach. For example:  `Dim success = False Dim retries = 10 While Not success AndAlso retries < 10 success = TryAction(AddressOf action1) If Not success Then retries += 1 End While`

Answer (score 0):

Move the Try/Catch blocks into the Action() methods.  This will allow you to respond to exceptions in each method differently, if necessary.

```
Sub Main()
  action1()
  action2()
  action3()
  action4()
End Sub

Sub Action1()
  Try
    '' do stuff
  Catch
    Log()
  End Try
End Sub

Sub Action2()
  Try
    '' do stuff
  Catch
    Log()
  End Try
End Sub

Sub Action3()
  Try
    '' do stuff
  Catch
    Log()
  End Try
End Sub

Sub Action4()
  Try
    '' do stuff
  Catch
    Log()
  End Try
End Sub
```